# Java : Load class based on user input

Tags: java

I have to get the class name from user and load it dynamically.

```
  public class sample{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length < 1)
    {
        print_usage();
    }
    else{
        Class inputClass = null;
        try {
            inputClass = Class.forName(args[0]);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
```

I have classes named Sample2, Sample3:

```
public class Sample2 {
    private String name;
}

public class Sample3 {
    private int value;
}
```

I want to load class based on user input, either Sample2/Sample3 class.

I have the files in the same directory, but I get the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Your classes are in package? You have added the directory to the classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be more clear on your question, I assume you are typing in the class names without the package.
If they're in a package, you must use Class.forName by that.

```
Class inputClass = null;
try {
    inputClass = Class.forName("my.package.MyClass");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. I was not giving the package name.

Comment: Is it possible to call the getter/setter/normal methods that are defined in the `inputClass`? I am only able to get the defined methods using `getDeclaredMethods()`, but I am not able to define an instance of the `inputClass` and call the methods passing arguments.

Comment: You could try to use `newInstance()`. But it's really evil.

Comment: Method[] methods = inputClass.getMethods();
methods[count].invoke(inputClass.newInstance(),inputString); 

I get java.lang.InstantiationException. Am I invoking the method right?

Comment: I figured what the problem was. I had defined a custom constructor and it seems newInstance() works only if no constructor is defined for the `inputClass`